# Need name(s) of electrical components to implement air raid siren

Tags: motor, siren

***I want to hook up 1 to many air raid sirens on the outside of my home to a weather radio.***

**Background:** I've lived 50 years in an area rural to Austin, TX, where we just had like 5 tornadoes in a 2 hour period.  I hadn't seen a sum of 5 tornadoes in the 49 years before the other day, much less had them buzzing by my house.  We happened to be watching the TV, then had a friend call us less than 5 minutes before the tornado passed by.  We're in what amounts to a pasture encircled on all sides by open land 1,000+ feet in every direction.  There is a busy, loud ass highway 1,400 feet from us.  I want an outdoor warning system to be heard by everyone within a radius of 1,000 - 1,500 feet from us.  Regarding electronics, I'm a virtual dullard, knowing almost **zero** words from the electronics lexicon.

I have purchased a weather alert radio,[Midland WR120B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00176T9OY), which has a 1/8 inch (3.5mm) phone plug into which one plugs devices such as [flashing lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002UB2K0) and [pillow shakers](https://midlandusa.com/collections/weather-sensory-alerts/products/shkr100-pillow-shaker-1).  I found this [forum post](https://forums.qrz.com/index.php?threads/wx-radio-external-alert-midland-wr-100.214508/) which says 12v of electricity gets turned on when there is an alert.  The relevant text is below.  I've found this [relay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MKWACVI) which looks like while exposed to a 12V charge, will push 110 V to something else.  I've found air raid sirens like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010EF9BGO), [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0831VNBTF), and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010EF9BGO).  The weather alert radio will continue to alert until someone touches a button on its display.  I assume that it will also stop after some length of time or when the weather alert / warning has ended.  I've learned that these air raid sirens are basically blower fans and if run full tilt can and will overheat.  Further, I have observed that a constant loud noise gets less attention than a noise which waxes and wanes.  Therefore, I'm looking for electrical components which will separately or in concert : slow down the motor or switch the motor on and off in a regular fashion, dare I say frequency, so that the siren gets as loud as it is gonna get, then spin down ( the sound dying down as well ), then spin back up ( the sound increasing as well ).  The nerd in me thinks that since the sound is directional, it would be cool ( or perhaps even necessary to cover the entire area of the circle ) if the siren itself also rotated on its vertical axis.  That would require another motor to rotate the platform upon which the siren is mounted.  I *think* the same type of component sought might be needed there too, so as to adjust the rate of rotation like a switch on a floor fan - high, medium, low.  So ... If you want to come to my place to solder all this up, then I'm game ( cause I can't solder for anything ), but otherwise, I would settle for answers to these topics / questions:

1. The name of an electrical component which will on its own speed up and slow down a motor?
2. The name of another electrical component which will allow me to adjust the speed of another motor?
3. How the heck could I keep from twisting up the power cord to the siren while the platform under it rotates?  [Electric cord reels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GJ7OBMU) have such a component, but again, I don't know what to call it.

Also, I am open to literally any advice on this project other than "don't do it".

**Forum Post**

```
Connecting the External Alert Output to an External Device

You may need to turn on or turn off another device when an alert is
received. The WR-100 provides a switch closure to signal other
devices at the EXT. ALERT jack when the monitor receives an alert.
The output is compatible with home automation devices from suppliers
like X-10 and others. Connect the positive lead of the interface to the
tip of the 1/8 inch (3.5mm) phone plug and the negative lead to the body
of the plug.

A DC powered device using 12 Volts or less and requiring less than
200mA of current can be switched directly using the EXT. ALERT jack.
Observe the polarity of the jack so that the negative side of the external
power source is connected to the body of the 1/8 inch (3.5mm) phone
plug and the device is connected to the positive source and to the tip of
the phone plug.

The internal switch is closed when an alert is received. Pressing any
button on the front of the monitor will open the switch.
```

Comment: I would like to answer, but I suspect what you are trying to do is probably illegal.  Since it involves line-voltage electrical work, it's also dangerous for a novice.  Can't you petition a county government official to do their job and install proper warning devices to serve your area?  (Just tell them "think of the children!" That always works with politicians.)

Comment: We used to have an air-raid siren down the street. It was strictly an electromechanical affair, powered by a massive 3-phase motor. There were [much bigger ones](https://www.deviantart.com/detroitdemigod/art/Hemi-powered-Air-Raid-Siren-201047788) powered by V8 internal combustion engines.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This. Drive a siren with a giant motor or even an engine. Way more powerful than an electric speaker.

Comment: They probably make something that turns something on and off every few seconds - probably too niche to be at the hardware store, but can be ordered online - not sure what it would be called, and this website is about designing your own electronics, not knowing what to buy from the online hardware store.

Comment: In Texas you will need to make sure it is bullet proof, because your neighbors will not appreciate your weekly tests or false alarms.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - I've got my neighbors covered, thanks.

Comment: @Theodore - nope.  I can't get them to fill potholes or stop flooding, much less this.

Comment: @Theodore - I don't understand the illegal comment.  If it is about noise ordinances, then I have that covered.  I also don't understand the line-voltage comment.  I'm glad you said it, cause that made me think of a dimmer switch for lights.  And like I said, I'm open to literally any advice other than "don't do it"

Comment: @user253751 - You CAN buy that "niche" product at a hardware store-a dimmer switch.  Now I just need to figure out how to get its settings range to swing back and forth on its own.  https://home.howstuffworks.com/dimmer-switch2.htm  "Instead of diverting energy from the light bulb into a resistor, modern resistors rapidly shut the light circuit off and on to reduce the total amount of energy flowing through the circuit. The light bulb circuit is switched off many times every second."  Apparently I need a variable resistor. Is there a site where I can ask electrical engineering questions?

Comment: @JeffMaass so... the dimmer switch is not the product you want, because it doesn't swing back and forth on its own... By the way, the siren is a huge heavy spinning thing, right? So you don't need to dim it, you can turn it fully off and it will take some time to slow down, then turn it fully on and it will take some time to speed up. (Have you ever heard an old-fashioned air raid/tornado/tsunami/etc siren? They do exactly this)

Comment: @DKNguyen - this is exactly what I'm proposing to do.  The air raid sirens I listed in the question are air horns driven by large motors.

Comment: @user253751 - yes, I have.  The old fashion air raid sirens are the products I listed in the question.  Now, how can I turn them on and off in an automated fashion?  Isn't there some sort of electrical component to do it for me?

Comment: @JeffMaass They probably make something that turns something on and off every few seconds - probably too niche to be at the hardware store, but can be ordered online - not sure what it would be called, and this website is about designing your own electronics, not knowing what to buy from the online hardware store.

Comment: @JeffMaass Relays or contactors are electrically controlled switches. But to make it pulse will require extra.

Comment: Repeat cycle timer on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/BN-LINK-Period-Repeat-Intermittent-Interval/dp/B0184CG9K0

Comment: @Theodore - That will solve Question 1 !  Thank you!